# Fit page to any screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a print template for my website everything it's OK but I have a problem, my screen resolution is 1600x900 so I design the page for that resolution, I'm talking about the height, because my page is created with Bootstrap so it's responsive, sound a little weird but let me explain it, the page in my screen looks like this:

**All this if for "print preview (ctrl + p)"**

```
Header
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Body
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Footer
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
```

But when I tried with others resolutions looks like this:

```
Header
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Body
Some text
Some text
Some text

Page 2
Some text
Footer
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
```

My question here is if exists a way to fit the page to the same height for any resolution, in other words show the page exactly of how it looks in my screen.

This is what I tried:

```
 p {
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    @page {
        size: A4 landscape;
        margin-left: 18mm;
        margin-top: 0.2mm;
    }
```

With that sometimes works, I don't expect that you code for me, but I expect some tips to solve this, thanks in advance and my apologize if this can't be understood

Comment: Review how to create [print stylesheets](http://www.webcredible.com/blog/print-stylesheet-definitive-guide/). There are many sites on the internet which explain how. Basically, you're going to need to do more work than just set the page size and margins.

Comment: I'm thinking about change the font size, margins, page size and all my content to fit it to the most common resolutions

Answer (score 0):

You’re approaching this problem wrong. There are an infinite variety of screen sizes out in the world. It's a mistake to design with a single resolution in mind. At best you can target a range of devices with similar dimensions, but then you're excluding a huge number of different devices.

Web pages do not need to look the same on every device. As soon as you internalize this, you’ll begin to become a better web designer.

All that said, you can use viewport units to ensure that that an element remains sized proportionally to to any screen size, but it's not going to be a one-size-fit-all solution, and I don't believe this works when you print.

For example:

`.container{
    height: 100vh
    width: 100vw;
}`

You can also use media queries to tell how the browser should *print* your web page, which are a good way to ensure a page prints the way you want it to. For example, instead of `@media screen and (min-width: 30em){…}` you can write `@media print and (min-width: 30em){}`.

Keep in mind your print stylesheets may already be using styles from other mobile or tablet media queries, so it can sometimes be a bit tricky, and you may need to override them. A printed document typically has a pretty narrow “viewport”.

Comment: I see what you meant and I think that my question is not much clear, page looks OK in any resolution because is responsive (I use Bootstrap) when I type ctrl + p I'm targeting to a certain div and in my screen I can print that div in one page, but when I do the same in another screen resolution I print that div in 2 pages or more that the problem I want to know if its possible to fit something to any resolution

Comment: I’ve edited to add information about print media queries, which may be what you're looking for.